# Apple Automator prompt user to enter folder name

Tags: macos, automator

Is it possible with Automator to create a new folder, but when doing so to have the user enter the location and name the older should be?

So, I take an image, scale and rename it, and save it to a new folder defined during the runtime?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this with Automator.

See attached screenshot:

(Note where the inputs are enabled between actions and where they are ignored)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know that it is possible with Action(s) ( http://app.jbbres.com/actions ) and as both softwares are pretty similar it is very likely that you can do it with Automator.

With Action(s), you choose the "Create new folder" action (I remember that there is an action with the same name in Automator) and check the "Show when running the workflow" box. I think that with automator there is a similar box in the option of the action.

Hope this help,